# Python - Pack 4 int into 4 bytes

Tags: python, colors, integer, byte, pack

I would like pack my color values in 4 bytes.

For example: having `(255,254,253,252)` I would like have back `b'\xff\xfe\xfd\xfc'`

Instead

```
r = 255
g = 254
b = 253
a = 252

tot = a << 3 | b << 2 | g << 1 | r

tot_byte = struct.pack('i', tot)
```

returns: `b'\xff\x07\x00\x00'`

if I do:

```
tot = a << 24 | b << 16 | g << 8 | r

tot_byte = struct.pack('i', tot)
```

I got back `"argument out of range".`

What I should do?

Comment: Yeah, I wrongly wrote, I meant datatype byte. "1 byte var"

Comment: `struct.pack('BBBB', r, g, b, a)`?

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is the Iain Shelvington's one:

```
struct.pack('BBBB', r, g, b, a)
```

or

```
struct.pack('4B', r, g, b, a)
```